# How can I check on which element the event was triggered?

Tags: javascript, html

```
addLBEvent : function()
    {
        var amount = this.imageList.length;
        for(var i = 0;i < amount;i++)
        {
            if(this.imageList[i].addEventListener)
            {
                this.imageList[i].addEventListener("click",this.startLB,false);
            }
            /* 
                IE<9-part
            */
        }
    },

startLB : function(src)
    {


    }
```

I'd like to know which element triggered the event.
If I'd do this in the HTML-Code I'd write something like `onlick="startLB(this.src)"` for example. How can I do such a thing with `addEventListener`?
I've already tried `addEventListener("click","myobjectname.startLB(this.src)" but it didn't work.

And sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
startLB : function(src)
    {
       var element = src.target.tagName;
       alert("element >> "+element);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

An event `object` is passed in as the first argument to any event handler.

The event object as a `target` property identifying the element to which the event applies.

```
addLBEvent : function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target

Answer (score 2):

You can access a reference to the element that triggered the event...

```
var elementThatTriggeredEvent = e.target || e.srcElement;
```

...assuming that `e` is the reference to the event.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which element was *clicked*, use `event.target`.

If you want to know which element you had the handler on, use `event.currentTarget` or, in most cases, `this`. `addEventListener` will call your handler with `this` set to the element on which you called `addEventListener`.

Note the distinction. For instance, if you had this markup:

```
<div id="foo"><span id="bar">Hi there</span></div>
```

...and this code:

```
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    alert(this.id);
    alert(event.target.id)
}, false);
```

...then if the user clicks the text "Hi there", `this` will be the `div` but `event.target` will be the `span`.

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/acuwuj) | [source](http://jsbin.com/acuwuj/edit)

See how `this` is the element you hooked the event on, and `event.target` is the element on which it fired (and then it bubbled up to the `div`).

---

Note that `addEventListener` isn't available on older versions of IE; you have to use `attachEvent` instead. `attachEvent` *doesn't* ensure that `this` is set to the element on which you hooked it, so beware that difference between APIs. To smooth things like that out, you might look to any decent library, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best for you to bind it like this:

```
var that = this;
this.imageList[i].addEventListener("click",function() {
    that.startLB(this.src);
},false);
```

`this` will become the event target, so we have to access the object somehow, I named that `that`

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
addLBEvent : function(e)
{
    if (!e) e = event;
    e = e.srcElement || e.target;
    .......
}
```